# Saving Excel Files to Sharepoint using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am attempting to run a query in Excel and update the data to Sharepoint (accessible via Teams) on a set schedule.

Desired folder destination:

```
https://rxsafeway.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/sites/EXELiveProductionTool/Shared%20Documents/General/Portland/Individual%20Performance%20Update?csf=1&web=1&e=oFwj6i
```

VBA code used:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="https://rxsafeway.sharepoint.com/sites/EXELiveProductionTool/Shared%20Documents/General/Portland/Individual%20Performance%20Update/" & ".xlsm"
```

Details:

-The above VBA code has been used successfully while connected to VPN *and* on the company network.

-It works inconsistently... Potentially an upload limit?

-Notice that the "/:f:/r/" has been removed, a "/" has been added after "Update", and everything passed "Update" has been removed in the working code

Question:

Sometimes the code works and sometimes I get a *Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed*

Is there a syntax error, or a smarter way to save the file?

Answer (score 0):

You probably getting this error due to the MAX_PATH 256 limitation.
Your filename is too long and therefore will have a longer Windows path as well.

I suggest you to view your SharePoint files in File Explorer (see the documentation [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/view-sharepoint-files-in-file-explorer-66b574bb-08b4-46b6-a6a0-435fd98194cc)). By doing so, every file/folder in your sharepoint will have a normal path and you'll not have anymore to use your file's url.

After that, you can use this formula to save your xlsm in some location in sharepoint :

```
Path="C:\Users\AKow\Sharepoint_Name\Path_to_your_file"
Filename = "Individual Performance Update"
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= Path & Filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Comment: Thank you, @L'Artiste. I will need others to view the output files in Teams, so I'm not sure using Sync will help. I attempted my original code again this morning (believing this is possibly a write to Sharepoint limitation in my network) and the code failed. I used your syntax and it worked once - then failed on the second attempt.